# Why initializing a UIImageView object with image returns nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkMark: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    checkMark = UIImageView(image: UIImage?)
}
```

I have initialize a object and set it with a UIImage. What I think is that this initialize a object with a picture in there, so it should show on screen, but it returns nil when `checkMark.isHidden = true`.

So, I use this method, just set an image in the assets to `checkMark.image`. It works, but I do not know what the difference is between these two.

```
checkMark.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "answerCheckMark.png")
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: checkMark = UIImageView(image: UIImage?) Is that what your actual code looks like? It shouldn't even compile...

Comment: It does compile, but It does not work just because I initialize a same object once again? This might be a stupid question, but I am new and just try to understand it.

Comment: As Sh_Khan wrote in his answer, you shouldn't create a new UIImageView and assign it to your outlet, since that's handled by the storyboard. Only change the image property of checkMark - set it to the UIImage you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems it's an outlet , so don't do this

```
checkMark = UIImageView(image:myImage)
```

as it will change reference of `weak var` to un-retained ( `UIImageView(image:myImage)`) rhs which will make it nil you may read the warning xcode shows in that line , so only change the image property

Comment: It means that, I have already initialize the object with an outlet. So I should not re initialize it, right? That makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I know the real difference. Feels good.